# How to add a number to its own index

Tags: c#

I will have a number which was taken as input from the use or i am storing a number assigned to a string as

```
  string s"1234567";
```

As for this the index of each string will be as 0,1,2,3,4 and so on

I would like to add the number with that index as 1+0, 2+1 , 3+2 and so on like that

so that the output should be 1,3,5 like that

Comment: What happens when a digit exceeds 9?

Comment: Do you have  fixed length numbers or could the input be 436 as well?

Comment: what do you want to do after adding them? re-concatenate?

Comment: "1,3,5"? So then you want the results converted back to strings and joined by commas?

Comment: I wonder who upvotes a vague and incomplete question like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string s = string.Join(",", valueString.Select(
     (c, i) => (i + (int)(c-'0')) % 10));
```

or in 2.0:

```
string[] result = new string[valueString.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < result.Length ; i++) result[i] =
         ((i + (int)(valueString[i] - '0')) % 10).ToString();
string s = string.Join(",", result);
```

Comment: Can i have this for non linq version i am using 2.0

Comment: @Dorabubu - added 2.0 version

Comment: Another help if i have 11,12 after addition i would like to have last digits as 1,2,3 and so on

Comment: Thanks both of you as i can mark only one i have marked this as answer

Comment: @Dora: "if i have 11,12 after addition i would like to have last digits as 1,2,3 " - then why didn't you say so?

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<int> IndexDigitSum(string s)
{
    for(int i=0;i<s.Length;i++)
    {
      int digit=s[i]-'0';
      if(digit<0||digit>9)
         throw new FormatException("Invalid Digit "+s[i]);
      yield return (digit+i)%10;
    }
}
```

In .net 2.0 you can replace yield return by adding to a local array:

```
int[] IndexDigitSum(string s)
{
    int[] result=new int[s.Length];

    for(int i=0;i<s.Length;i++)
    {
      int digit=s[i]-'0';
      if(digit<0||digit>9)
         throw new FormatException("Invalid Digit "+s[i]);
      result[i]=(digit+i)%10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or if you want them concated:

```
string IndexDigitSum(string s)
{
    string[] parts=new string[s.Length];

    for(int i=0;i<s.Length;i++)
    {
      int digit=s[i]-'0';
      if(digit<0||digit>9)
         throw new FormatException("Invalid Digit "+s[i]);
      parts[i]=((digit+i)%10).ToString();
    }
    return string.Join(",", parts);
}
```

To get the last digit of the sum one can simply add a %10 because the last digit of a number is it's remainder modulo 10.

Comment: Another help if i have 11,12 i would like to have last digits as 1,2,3 and so on.